# Identifying location of a body in simple harmonic motion given the speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

> Say the particle at point 1 in time is at $x=+0.5A$ moving towards the equilibrium where $A$ is amplitude and after a $t$ amount of seconds, the particle is 1/3 of the maximum speed moving away from the equilibrium passing the equilibrum once.

I understand that at point 1 it is in the first quadrant and the angle is calculated as pi/3 and also that point 2 exists inside the second quadrant as it has passed through the equilibrium once and moves away from it, but how do I use the 1/3 of the maximum speed to figure out where it is at point 2?

Comment: Do you the conceptual (symbolic?) value of the maximum speed of a simple harmonic oscillator? And you are making an assumption that x=A when t=0. I don't know if that's right or wrong, but you need to be aware of your assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

The simple harmonic motion equation is

$$ x(t) = A\cos(\omega t - \phi),$$

where $\omega$ is the angular velocity and $\phi$ is a phase. You can figure out what the velocity is:

$$v(t) = \frac{dx}{dt} = -A\omega \sin(\omega t - \phi).$$

Now you can play with this:

- At time $t=0$, find the phase $\phi$ for which $x(0)=+0.5A$.
- Find the maximum speed, and 1/3 of the maximum speed.
- Note that if initially the particle is moving towards the equilibrium, then the velocity must be negative at that point! So it the particle will pass through the equilibrium point. Now you should be able to solve for $t$ in the following equation:
  $$ v_{max}/3 = -A\omega\sin(\omega t - \phi).$$
  Note that the $t$ that you solved for must satisfy the left hand side to be negative, since the particle is moving away from the equilibrium.
- Plug this time in $x(t)$ to know the position of the particle.